# How to make object's key is of type values of an array (values should be optional and not mandatory)

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, key, typeof

I am facing a situation where I need to give the object's key is of another array's values, like this

```
const temp: { [key in typeof someArray[number] ]: string[] } = {
   'animal': ['dog', 'cat']
} // ERROR - missing the following properties from type birds ...  

const someArray = [ 'animals', 'birds' ] as const;
```

This makes the temp object should contain keys of all the values inside the array.
But, I **needed** to **make the values optional** ie., If there is any key then it needs to be one among the values of the array, if some values are not there as keys then there should be no issues

```
const temp: { [key in typeof someArray[number] ]: string[] } = {
   'animal': ['dog', 'cat']
} // This shouldn't considered as an error 

const temp: { [key in typeof someArray[number] ]: string[] } = {
   'animal': ['dog', 'cat'],
   'random': ['random_1']
} // But this should throw an error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the type of `temp` a `Partial`:

```
const temp: Partial<{ [key in typeof someArray[number] ]: string[] }> = {
    'animals': ['dog', 'cat']
}
```

(btw. 'animals' instead of 'animal')

`Partial` makes every field optional.

And I recommend using a `type` instead of an array:

```
const temp: Partial<{ [key in SomeArray]: string[] }> = {
    'animals': ['dog', 'cat']
}

type SomeArray = 'animals' | 'birds';
```